# Some properties about $L^p$ with $0<p<1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

We are coming across many Banach spaces $L^p$ with $1\leq p\leq\infty$. But how about $0<p<1$? Can it be normed? How about its metric induced by the norm? And how about its convexity,completeness and reflexiveness? And moreover,can we define functionals on it?

Comment: In the "usual" topology, given by $\lvert f\rvert_p = \int \lvert f(x)\rvert^p\, dx$ (note: no $p$-th root for $0 < p < 1$), the space is not normable, the only non-empty convex open set is the entire space, hence there are no continuous linear functionals on it except $0$.

Comment: I should verify these carefully,thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the map $t\mapsto t^p$ is sub-additive, one can define on $L^p$ the metric 
$$\rho(f,g):=\int_X|f(x)-g(x)|^p\mathrm dx.$$
This metric is complete.

However it can be shown that the topological vector space $L^p$ with this metric is not locally convex ($0\lt p\lt 1$). Furthermore, the *topological* dual of this topological vector space is reduced to the null functional.

Comment: It is just an F-space.